# How to get product list Magento using rest api

Tags: magento-1.9

How to get product list in magento using rest API. I need to use it for product sync . How to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know about the Magento REST API can be found here in the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html (that link is specific to your product related question)

Comment: I am new to API, i need to give my all products to Android based application, how can i do that, using REST API where i need to start and give my products to Android Application.  Any docs welcome @Raphael at Digital Pianism

Answer (score 0):

You need to call in postman like these to get product list

```
Method:- GET
URL:- http:yourlUrl/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[page_size]=20
```